# R table() labels

Tags: r

I have 30 columns of qualitative data which I want to transform in quantitative data.

Firstly I want to find out what values are stored in each column and then replace each instance of this value with a number.  I can use either table() or summary() to get a frequency table for each data value but then I am unable to access these values - I can only get the frequencies which I don't care about.  I have also looked at unique() and duplicated() to no avail.

For example for the first column I have 10,000 rows containing either "dummy1", "dummy2", "dummy3", "dummy4" or "dummy5".  I want to replace these values with 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 respectively.

table(data) gives me a summary of the frequency for each qualitative value but I'm unable to isolate the values "dummy1" etc in a variable (which I will later match to replace).  Because I have 30 columns of data I don't want to hard code these dummy values.  Unique() only gives the unique value but I want a list of each possible value.

Any help would be much appreicated.

Comment: Try using which() to find the indices of each expression you want to convert. Example:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using which() to find the indices of each expression you want to convert. The following example should be enough to get you started. You can expand this idea to the whole data set with a loop or functional statement:

```
a <- c("dummy1", "dummy1", "dummy2", "dummy1", "dummy3")
df <- data.frame(a=a, b=a, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
print(df)
index <- which(df[1]=="dummy1")
df[index, 1] = 3
print(df)


> print(df)
       a      b
1 dummy1 dummy1
2 dummy1 dummy1
3 dummy2 dummy2
4 dummy1 dummy1
5 dummy3 dummy3
> index <- which(df[1]=="dummy1")
> df[index, 1] = 3
> print(df)
       a      b
1      3 dummy1
2      3 dummy1
3 dummy2 dummy2
4      3 dummy1
5 dummy3 dummy3
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I didn't want to hard code "dummy1".  I don't know what the categories are in each column and I have 30 columns.  I have stumbled across what I was looking for in another question... levels(as.factor(dataCol)).  This gives me a list of the categories in the column "dataCol".

However, your code is what I'll need for the next step so thanks very much!